# Hitting left arrow in my Mac terminal during a console program execution displays characters ^[[D. Why?

Tags: mac, terminal, shell

These work fine when typing in the shell itself (no child processes, just the prompt) - I can edit the input line before submitting it as command input to the shell. But when I am running a program, say Standard ML interpreter (SML New Jersey) in the same terminal, I cannot move the caret back on my line to edit out stuff, instead it adds the sequence `^[[D` to the end of output. Is it because the program simply does not interpret my arrow keys the way I want it to? Perhaps it doesn't even support such editing mode?

Comment: I think this question explains it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911861/how-to-fix-the-sml-nj-interactive-system-to-use-arrow-keys

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) and [this Kermit page](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/k95manual/arrow.html) discuss the history of ANSI establishing “escape sequences” for non-ASCII keys (including “ESC [ D” for left arrow) and cursor functions, and the DEC VT100 being an early adopter of the standard.